# Find creates a file when I use {}

Tags: linux, shell, find

I try to use find to create a very simple way to add newline to a file. I know there are tons of other ways to do this but it bugs the hell out of me that I cannot get this way to work.
So - I'm NOT asking how to add newline to a file - I'm asking why find is weird.

```
find . -type f -iname 'file' -exec echo >> {} \;
```

results in a new file created named "{}" with the newline in while (to check that find works on my computer):

```
find . -type f -iname 'file' -exec echo {} \;
```

prints "./file".

So the >> makes find confused. The question is why and how do I solve that?

Comment: `So the >> makes find confused.` It doesn't, its handled by the shell, not passed to find.

Comment: Ok... how do I write to create the desired effect (add a newline to the file I found) with find and exec?? Or how do I force >> to be passed to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm asking why find is weird.

It isn't. This has nothing to do with `find`. In fact, when the file is created, `find` hasn't even started to run.

`>>` roughly means "redirect stdout to the end of this file, create a new file when necessary". Note how nothing of this has anything to do with whatever is *left* of the `>>`.

Redirection is a feature of the shell, `find` knows nothing about the redirection and the shell knows nothing about `find`. `>>` doesn't magically change its meaning just because you happened to call `find`. It still means the exact same thing.

If you want to use a shell feature whithin `-exec`, you need to use a shell within `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -iname 'file' -exec sh -c 'echo >> "{}"' \;
```

Comment: You cannot force `>>` to be parsed by `find`. `>>` is a feature of the POSIX shell. `find` is not a POSIX shell.

Comment: Your untested solution didn't seem to work, but thanks for trying. :D Now i know more.

Comment: @Mr.Glaurung, works for me. Are you sure it's not adding newlines to the end of the file(s)?

Comment: @Mr.Glaurung: Fixed missing level of quoting.

Answer (score 1):

While the question itself has already been answered, I'd like to point out that you don't strictly need to make `find` do everything, rather you can use other available facilities to work together with it, for example:

```
find . -type f -iname 'file' | while read file; do echo >>"$file"; done
```

This approach also has the advantage of not executing a new process for every match, which is irrelevant in this case but potentially important if there are thousands of matches and the `exec` is relatively heavy.

Comment: edge case: this will break for any filename that contains a newline. The safer way to do this is (requires GNU find): `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ...`

Comment: @glennjackman Good point for general education, but in this case the find condition excludes the possibility as it matches by name.

Comment: re. my above comment: the path itself could contain newlines, so my statement was incorrect. However, I would hope that anyone running a find that modifies all matched files would only do so in an environment where they know all possible matches and whether they need to account for possible newlines. =)